# Parse single URL without crawlling

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a single url with scrapy. I don't want it to crawl, just parse the item, run the pipelines and return. My pipeline just updates the database. The following code is what i've done so far and is taking around 3 seconds but seems like most of the time is spend loading scrapy. If there a better way todo this?

Ideally I want to parse a single url from a python script and not command line.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('start_url')]


def parse(self, response):
    if 'item.asp' in response.url:
        yield Request(response.url, callback=self.parse_item)
```

Then i'm running from command line like the following

```
time scrapy crawl --loglevel=DEBUG MySpider -a start_url="www.example.com"
```

I did also try the following but never worked with the pipeline parameter.

```
time scrape parse "www.example.com" --spider=MySpider --callback parse_item --pipelines AddToDB
```

Comment: Is your question about the performance of your solution? or is something not working (feature-wise, data-wise) as expected?

Comment: @paultrmbrth More about performance. The first command works and runs but trying to find a solution that might be a bit more efficient. Also ideally I want to run this from a python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the documentation for `scrapy parse` http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html?highlight=parse#std:command-parse
In your case you are misunderstanding the `--pipelines` argument. it enables **all** of the pipelines defined in the `settings.py`

so just run without `AddToDB`.

If you want to disable some pipelines from running it might be tricky and you might want to just have a child of your spider, add class attribute `custom_settings` and restrict the pipelines in it.
So in your case something like:

```
class MySpider2(MySpider):
    name = 'spider2'
    custom_settings = {'ITEM_PIPELINES': 'project.pipelines.AddToDB'}
```

and then use `scrapy parse 'http://example.com' --spider=spider2 --pipelines`.

Comment: Thanks that's why I couldn't get the parse command working. Unfortunately this is slower and takes 5-7 seconds for one URL.

Comment: if you want more speed you should look into scrapyRT https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyrt which is especially designed for what you are looking for here.

Comment: Looks great, i'll give it a go. Thanks